# Freeform Pro Won't Register Form Submissons

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, forms

We have a relatively simple form that won't register any submissions even though there is no outward sign of an error. Manual submissions via the CP work just fine. I'm trying out FF to use FF Pro on a new site.

I have tried varying parameters with little to no luck. I've noticed some issues with Freeform so I'm assuming this is something on our end.
EE 2.93 and FF Pro 4.2.4

The site is located at: http://www.apothekergroup.com/site/test

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

```
    {exp:freeform:form
form_id="3"
return="_forms/thank-you" 
notify_admin="yes"
notify="justin@suissa.com"
admin_template="admin_user_registration_notication"
form_name="initial_event_registration"

    }


                                <div class="row mar-lr-none">
                                    <div class="large-12 columns">
                                        <label> <h6 class="bold primary-color"> STEP 1/3: </h6> </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="large-12 columns">
 <p>
        <label>{freeform:label:full_name}</label>
        {freeform:field:full_name}

    </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="large-12 columns">
   <p>
        <label>{freeform:label:email}</label>
        {freeform:field:email}

    </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="large-12 columns">
   <p>
        <label>{freeform:label:confirm_email}</label>
        {freeform:field:confirm_email}

    </p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="large-12 columns">
   <p>


    </p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="large-12 columns text-right">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="XID" value="{XID_HASH}" /> 
                                {freeform:submit}


                        </div>
                                </div>

                        </div>
                        {/exp:freeform:form}
```

Comment: You don't need both `form_id=""` and `form_name=""`: one or the other is enough. Also no need for the `XID` hidden field if you're on EE 2.9.3 (that was for EE 2.7 and under). Have you had a look at our troubleshooting guide? :)
http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/troubleshooting/ In particular I'd check your EE redirection setting and show (or describe) the contents of your .htaccess file in the above post.

Comment: If it helps after trying a lot of the troubleshooting the URL that appears is: `http://www.apothekergroup.com/site/test/?params_id=282&csrf_token=a73f389a88a3373313ab2191429cf62cca4b8fcf&full_name=&email=&confirm_email=&XID=a73f389a88a3373313ab2191429cf62cca4b8fcf&submit=Submit`

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a shot at it.

A common issue...

When you visit `Members -> Member Preferences` in your Control Panel, is your `Require Terms of Service` preference set to `Yes`? If so, I think you need to put a checkbox in your FreeForm form to get past that in front-end registrations. Try setting that preference to `No`.

Comment: That's interesting, but from my use of Freeform isn't that completely different? The registration of new EE members vs. tracking Freefrorm registrations?

Comment: Is this form registering users in a way that puts them in the EE members table?

Comment: I don't believe so, but I noticed when I manually enter data it uses my current member name, but there's just 3 fields name and email and confirm email. I made my system folder in the default locale and got rid of the htaccess all to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The cause here was an .htaccess file that needed tweaking (usually this is a good start: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/remove_index.php.html), and the removal of an outer `<form>...</form>` HTML tag pair unrelated to Freeform (can't have a form within a form in HTML).